# How to edit an embedded macro in Access 2013

Tags: vba, ms-access, macros, ms-office

I have an .accdb database and I tried the following ways of editing an embedded macro named "AutoExec":

- Visual Basic editor does not show it (I guess because it is embedded, not named)
- the macro is displayed in the Navigation Pane, but right-clicking it does not show any context menu
- based on http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-access/how-do-i-open-an-existing-macro-for-editing-in-ms/c28c7874-5435-4fd2-a4a6-d6562fb47492 I opened the Property Sheet of the macro and some forms but there is no ellipsis to click on, looks like this:
  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWqVS.png)

The macro creates an exception and is interrupted immediately after opening the database. I want to repair it. Thank you very much for any input.

Comment: most probably your applications true extension is accde. which prohibits editing macros.

Comment: That sounds interesting - yes, there are two files with the same name in the folder, one accdb and the other accde. What options do I have? Any chance of unlocking it?

Comment: Edit the macro in the ACCDB version and then create a new ACCDE from the updated ACCDB.

Comment: If an AutoExec macro is causing grief, you can prevent it from running by holding down the Shift key when opening the accdb file.

Answer (score 0):

If you press F11, you get a window in the left hand side with a list of tables, forms, reports, macros, and modules.  Expand the modules section and right click on the AutoExec macro.  Choose Design View

You should now see what it does.

Comment: Thank you, but I am afraid it does not apply to this case. Right-clicking the macro does not show any context menu. Maybe I should get a different Office version or something to cross-check.